# How to get id when edit button is clicked in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I can't find a way to get id when button is clicked on a certain row. The row gets added in map function by filling add form. I want the **id attribute** to have the id of that object which I passed and stored in localStorage.
Then I want to get the id and print it on console in **editStudent** function.

```
const Admin = () =>{

    const classes = useStyle();
    const history = useHistory();
    const[token, setToken] = React.useState(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    const[name, setName] = React.useState(localStorage.getItem('Admin'))
    let student = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student'))

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(token === null){
            return history.push('/')
        }else if(student === null){
          return history.push('/admin')
        }
    },[token])
  

    const rows = []
    if(student === null){
      // return history.push('/admin')
    }
    else{
      for(let i = 0; i < student.length ; i++){
        rows.push(student[i])
      }
    }
const editStudent = (id)=>{


  console.log(id);

  // localStorage.setItem('uniqID',localStorage.getItem('id'))

  // return history.push('/admin/edit')

}

    const LogOut = () =>{
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        setToken(null)
        setName('');
    }
    const Add = () => {
      history.push('/admin/add')
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static" className = {classes.Appbar}>
                <Toolbar className = {classes.Toolbar}>
                    <Typography variant="h6">{name} <span style={{color: '#df1b39'}}><strong>Dashboard</strong></span></Typography>
                    <Button color="secondary" className = {classes.button} variant = "contained" onClick={LogOut}>Logout</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div>
                <div className = {classes.head}>
                  <h1>Student Details</h1>
                  <Button onClick={Add}><AddCircleIcon fontSize = 'large' color = 'primary'/>Add Student</Button>
                </div>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <TableContainer component = {Paper}>
                    <Table>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <StyleTableCell>#</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell>Roll Number</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell>Full Name</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell>Father's Name</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell>Phone Number</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell>Email address</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell>Semester #</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell>CGPA</StyleTableCell>
                          <StyleTableCell align='right'>Action</StyleTableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                    {
                      rows.map((row,i) =>{
                        return <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>{i+1}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{row.Rnumber}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{row.Fname}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{row.Pnumber}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{row.email}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{row.semester}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{row.CGPA}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell align = 'right'>
                                <span>
                                <Button id='1' variant = 'outlined' onClick={editStudent(this.id)} style={{color : 'yellow', border : '1px solid yellow', marginRight : '10px'}}>
                                  Edit
                                </Button>
                                <Button variant = 'outlined' style={{color : 'red', border : '1px solid red' }}>
                                  Delete
                                </Button>
                                </span>
                          </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    })}
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id from `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`

```
const editStudent = (event)=>{

  console.log(event.target.id); // or try event.currentTarget.id

  // localStorage.setItem('uniqID',localStorage.getItem('id'))

  // return history.push('/admin/edit')

}
```

```js
<Button id='1' onClick={editStudent}>
 Edit
</Button>
```